# capturing html markup from web part

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010

Good day

Im developing a visual SharePoint web part and i have hit a speed bump. 1 of my requirements require me to get the html markup of the web part. The problem is that i cannot override Render() as this always circles back.

My question is that is there any other way to get the web parts html markup?

Comment: what do you mean by "this always circles back"?

Comment: If i were to use render, it over writes the changes i plan to make.. Redirecting to a generated PDF